# webservice Cannot assign object of type System.Xml.XmlNode[] to an object of type System.String

Tags: java, vb.net, web-services, wsdl

I am trying to consume a Java Webservice using Visual Basic.net. I am getting an error on deserialization "Cannot assign object of type System.Xml.XmlNode[] to an object of type System.String".

What I have been reading is that the wsdl specification may not conform to the WS-I BP 1.1 specification. [Link Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/f550e2b2-af9e-4653-a618-cffffdc70fdf/)

The other solution talked about [here](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/426522-system-invalidcastexception-cannot-assign-object-type-system-xml-xmlnode-object-type-system-string) is to change the response xml to conform to a .net datatype. I have tried to do this for other reasons a couple of years back and it proved to be unstable.

A snippet of the wsdl is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://ws.interfaces.sessions.APILink.amdocs" 
xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" 
xmlns:impl="http://ws.interfaces.sessions.APILink.amdocs" 
xmlns:intf="http://ws.interfaces.sessions.APILink.amdocs" 
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:tns2="http://io.datainfo.APILink.amdocs" 
xmlns:tns3="http://datainfo.APILink.amdocs" 
xmlns:tns4="http://awsi.amdocs.com" 
xmlns:tns5="http://exceptions.APILink.amdocs" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

 <complexType name="InPersonInfo">
        <complexContent>
          <extension base="tns2:BaseInputOutputInfo">
             <sequence>    
              <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="mItem1" type="xsd:int"/>
              <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="mID" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>    
              <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="mPersonType" type="tns4:char"/>    
            </sequence>    
          </extension>    
        </complexContent>    
      </complexType>
```

The other pieces from the WSDL I am seeing is just the message and operation sections.

EDIT 2011-04-21: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486647/using-java-webservice-in-net) mentions what I am going through.

I am not familiar with java what I know is that it is being created/consumed with AXIS or SOAPUI and somehow it is not creating the WSDL according to standard and there is my problem. If I find an answer to solve it I will post it here.